# mechanism of "run" method of failsafe

Tags: java, exception, retry-logic, java-failsafe

I am using `Failsafe` (https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) as my retry logic framework and want to know more of how "run" method of failsafe works.

Suppose I have:

```
void MyCurrentFunction(parameter) {
    Failsafe.with(MY_RETRY_POLICY)
            .run(() -> runJob(parameter));
    OtherFunction1();
}
```

Then when `MyCurrentFunction` runs, will `Failsafe.run` blocks execution of MyCurrentFunction? In other words, will `OtherFunction1` be executed before all retries finishes?

Comment: I think the code is synchronous, but you could test it very easily yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that checks your question (Note: the code is related Failsafe 2.0)

```
private RetryPolicy<Object> MY_RETRY_POLICY = new RetryPolicy<>()
        .handle(RuntimeException.class)
        .withMaxRetries(3);

private void myCurrentFunction() {
    Failsafe.with(MY_RETRY_POLICY)
            .run(() -> runJob());

    otherFunction1();
}

private void otherFunction1() {
    System.out.println("OtherFunction1");
}

private void runJob() {
    System.out.println("run job...");

    throw new RuntimeException("Exception");
}
```

The answer is **No**; `OtherFunction1` will not be executed before all retries finishes.
Actually, if all retries fail `OtherFunction1` will never be invoked.

Here is the output for test code

```
run job...
run job...
run job...
run job...

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception
```

Still, you can modify the retry policy to execute `OtherFunction1`
1) After each retry

```
private RetryPolicy<Object> MY_RETRY_POLICY = new RetryPolicy<>()
        .handle(RuntimeException.class)
        .onRetry(fail -> otherFunction1())
        .withMaxRetries(3);
```

2) After retries fail

```
private RetryPolicy<Object> MY_RETRY_POLICY = new RetryPolicy<>()
        .handle(RuntimeException.class)
        .onFailure(fail -> otherFunction1())
        .withMaxRetries(3);
```